# Qt app on Android without Ministro

Tags: android, qt, qt-necessitas, ministro

I want deploy app with Qt 4 or 5 libs (Core & GUI) in apk. Is it real? I use necessitas to create apps. google.com didn't help in this answer.

P.S.: sorry for my English, it's not my native language.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean that you don't want to use Ministro, then it should be possible.  The page below gives some directions how to:

http://community.kde.org/Necessitas/QuickStartDevelop

On March 1, 2013, the page above has the following:

> Deploy Configurations
>
> Also on the Run view you can set the Deploy Configurations, by selecting Details at the right hand side these are the different options you can choose between.
>
> 1. Use device's qt libs
> 2. Deploy local qt libs
> 3. Install Ministro system
>
> The Use devices qt libs option depends also on the Use local qt libs option. When Use local qt libs is unchecked your application will need the Ministro package to run. However if Use local qt libs is checked, Qt Creator will pass special parameters to the application, forcing it to use Qt libraries from the /data/local/qt path on the device.
>
> The Deploy local qt libs option makes Qt Creator deploy qt libs found in the Qt SDK chosen (e.g. android-lighthouse-4.8.0). This option is useful when you hack on the Qt framework to test it. This option automatically selects the Use local qt libs option. This option get automatically unchecked after Qt Creator pushes the Qt libs. This option can be checked every time you need to push your local Qt modifications.
>
> Install Ministro system option installs the Ministro package (you must provide the apk yourself; download it from from here). It is useful when you try to test your application on Android Virtual Devices.

If you want to go with Ministro for the libraries, here are directions on how to get it set up:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.licentia.necessitas.ministro

http://sourceforge.net/p/necessitas/home/necessitas/

> What is Ministro ?
>
> Necessitas is also the Home of Ministro, an Android application which provides a system wide downloader and installer of the LGPL Qt shared libraries. You can find Ministro on the Android Market or as direct download here.

EDIT: Some more links:

http://community.kde.org/Necessitas

http://necessitas.kde.org/

http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_Create_and_Run_Qt_Application_for_Android

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, i want to use my app without Ministro, but i want insert all libs in apk. Users will not understand when my app will start download libs. I want to install _only_ my apk to run my app. Cat i do this when "Deploy local qt libs" select? May be i must install some libs on pc? If yes, i could not do it. All information about this in English language, it's so hard.

Comment: For example, i think i must place libs, plugins, etc into /data/local/qt. How i can do this before run my main Qt app's bit? Or what?

Comment: After reading some more, in the Mailing List Area it looks like you can't embed the dlls right now. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/android-qt and here is the thread that explains it: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-qt/ELyOYXbVc5Y

Comment: I can try include some code in myapp/android/src/org/qtproject/qt5/android/bindings/QtActivity.java , what can unzip libs before run another code, but i don't know Java, but i try. If it will work, i write about this here. Thank you very much for help.